# Reorder generic properties in Umbraco CMS

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6

This question relates to Umbraco CMS version 6.1.4.

I create a new **Document Type** and some generic properties for it.

I am able to arrange the properties in the properties editor:

[image]

But it makes no difference in the **Content** section.

[image]

Umbraco, Y U NO sort my attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a bug. One that I fixed at the UK Hackathon at the end of last year. The generic properties tab wasn't honouring the order of the generic properties. You can see more details  [on the Umbraco issue tracker here](http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-2757)

If you upgrade to 6.2, the issue should be fixed.